Transforming a jar into a banana using shape keys
I want to make a transformation from a jar to a banana (morph) using shape keys. Using SimpleDeform, I made a semicircle out of a jar and now I need to draw the banana's limbs.
How can I do it?
In Edit Mode, it is not possible to change the object received in Simple Deform; it suggests changing the original object.


Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Please don't ask the same questions twice. @moonboots already provided a working solution on your previous question. If there is something in the answer you are struggling with, ask for clarification there.

Try to apply the deform modifier as shapekey, you can find that option next to the common "apply modifier" option. That way you are able to change the mesh in edit mode without destroying the original mesh. After you applied the modifier as shapekey, go to the "data" menu in your properties area (the green triangle). The shape key menu should now show 2 entries, the first labeled as "base" the second probably something like "Key 1". In edit mode klick on the second one and start editing your mesh. When you're done, change the value for the second key to see your object morph. Hope that's solving your problem.
